# How to make an imported 3D Image look like X-Ray?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, plot-themes, image3d

I have a human chest data as below:-

```
data3D = BlockchainGet[   "ecfe5311a6b5ae164aca82b58c630e150ab93b1fd1b0c9d0b48e276e624b51c7"];
Show[Image3D[data3D], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {Style["z", Bold, 16], Style["y", Bold, 16], Style["x", Bold, 16]}]
```

[image]

How can I make it looks like a x-ray? For example, something similar to below:-

[image]

For plot, there may be something like `PlotTheme -> "XRay"`, but it is not supported by `Image3D`. Or are there any other method to make to more alike a x-ray?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe AnatomyPlot3D is something you are looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the builtin [`ColorFunction -> "XRay"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3D.html#390761586):

```
Image3D[data3D, ColorFunction -> "XRay", Background -> Black]
```

[image]

We can use custom rendering options to make the x-ray more prominent:

```
Show[
  Image3D[data3D, ColorFunction -> "XRay", 
    Method -> {"VolumeLighting" -> "EnhancedEdge","InterpolateValues" -> True}],
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
  Background -> Black, Boxed -> False
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add the box back? I tried to add `Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {Style["z", Bold, 16], Style["y", Bold, 16], Style["x", Bold, 16]}` back to `Show`, but then the blackground disappeared.

Comment: I noticed that too. I think adding `Background -> Black` as an option to `Show` will fix it.

Comment: @H42 I do not think it is just a matter of color function or lighting or background. 3-D rendering is for volume data inspection and assumes some viewpoint of an observer. X-ray projection needs to assume a focal spot and a screen (film, dector array). This is quite a different geometry!